# How to write $r(a) = \lim_{n\to∞}r_n(a)$ as an infinite product?

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

Define
$$\begin{align}r_1&:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R, a\to\sqrt{a} \\
r_{n+1}&:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R, a\to\sqrt{a+r_n(a)}&\forall n\in\mathbb 
N\end{align}$$
and $r(a) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}r_n(a)$.
I want to write $r(a)$ as an infinite product, but I don't even know where to begin. If it helps I have worked out the limit
$$r(a)  = \frac {1+\sqrt{1+4a}}2$$

Comment: To give a proper definition of $r_n$, you should say something about $r_1$.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ChrisEagle So I can have a changing coefficient in front of a which changes with the production. Basically so I can represent this: $\sqrt{c_1a+\sqrt{c_2a+\sqrt{c_3a+\sqrt{c_4a\dots}}}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an infinite product:

\begin{align}
r(a)&=\sqrt a \times \frac{\sqrt{a+\sqrt a}}{\sqrt a} \times \frac{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt a}}}{\sqrt{a+ \sqrt a}}\times\dots\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^\infty s_j(a)
\end{align}

where $s_1(a)=\sqrt a$ and $s_j$ is defined as $r_j/r_{j-1}$ for $j\ge 2$, according to the iterative definition given for $r_n$ in your question.

Comment: Is there anymore explanation to how you deduced the answer?

Comment: Yes, **telescopy**. Wikipedia has an article on [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series); see if you can translate the additive ideas there into the multiplicative realm.

Comment: Given an arbitrary convergent sequence $f_n$ of functions, let $g_1=f_1$, and let $g_n=f_n/f_{n-1}$ for $n\ge2$.  Then $g_1=f_1$, $g_1\times g_2=f_1\times(f_2/f_1)=f_2$, $g_1\times g_2\times g_3=f_2\times (f_3/f_2)=f_3$ and, in general, $\prod_{n=1}^Ng_n=f_N$.  So, by the definition of an infinite product, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty g_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}[f_N]$.